How do I display the count and name of services checked off from Salesforce in Power BI?
enter image description here
The above image is the checkbox in Salesforce that I would like to display in power bi. I'm hoping to display the count in one column and the services checked off in a separate column but concatenated so there's not a row for each service.
Below is what I'm hoping for:



Count
Services




2
Call to Collateral, Case Management


1
Community Visit, Employee Coordination



This is the part of my query I used to group the Service Names but unfortunately it's displaying records where one service is checked off and not multiple:
= Table.Group(#"Expanded Service", {"Service Entry (3).Name"}, {{"Grouped Service Name", each Text.Combine([#"Direct Service (3).ExpECM__Service_Name__c"],","), type nullable text}})
This also happens often where the same service is in the column twice but only checked off once in Salesforce:
enter image description here
enter image description here

maybe you can try this in PQ
split the delimiter to rows


